# using jQuery to reload entire page

Tags: jquery

Can I use `jQuery.load()` or and other jQuery function to load the entire page?

Edit: I am looking for the ability to include data that the jQuery functions offer.

Comment: Any more specifics? Are you trying to reload on click? At an interval?

Comment: What "data that the jQuery functions offer" do you mean? The ability to pass parameters?

Comment: include data how? A usage example could help clarify

Comment: I have an array that I would like to pass to the new page as post data.  It is not coming from a form.

Comment: @Pointy henchman's answer seems to offer a bit of value to this question- using JQuery to boot.  Not that I disagree with you about OP's misunderstanding.

Comment: @Matt But he wants the POST response to replace the current page. Yes, he's using jQuery, and he's using it to create a form on the page and submit it.  See question 2367979 where Brian was given the exact same advice.

Comment: @Pointy I'm pretty sure .submit() actually, _literally_, submits the form.  It isn't some sort of AJAX call or anything.

Comment: Uhh, yes, I know - and given that what Brian wants is for the server response to the POST to completely replace the page - like, what the browser does when you POST a form - that seems like the right thing to do.

Comment: Ha sorry, I guess I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need jQuery for that.  Just do:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: For those who can't get this to work - it may be that your page is cached, which you can solve by adding this neat trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338800/cakephp-jquery-location-reload-sometimes-not-working/6658863#6658863

Answer (score 3):

As you would like to have the information in a new page (the old being totaly replaced by new content IS a new page), ajax is not the answer, because it is used to place new content in an old page.

i would recommend injecting a form into the current page using javascript and submitting this form programmatically.

Quick'n'dirty (untested):

```
$("#formsPlaceholder").append('<form action="newpage" method="post" id="newForm"><input type="textfield" name="foo" value="bar"/></form>');
$("#newForm").submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery. `location.reload();` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to refresh the page, or load the contents of a file into the page? To refresh the page you can call window.history.go(). To load another page into the body of this page, you can call $("body").load("path/to/other/page.html"). The other html page should not include the html, head or body tags, just the content of the body.

Comment: I also have a lot of stuff in the head, is it possible to just do the entire page?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following at the required point should re: GET the page... unless i'm mistaken..

```
window.location = window.location;
```

Comment: location.reload() as per the others. don't use this :)