# CakePHP & JQuery, location.reload sometimes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

Hi I am developing data deleting page with checkbox and button. After deletion, I'd like to display the message either the transaction is successful or not. Most of the time the message shows correctly, but sometimes the page reload doesn't happen and the message won't show until manually reloaded.
Now if it's not certain if the page is reloaded, is there any other way to show the message from the controller?
Here's the code:

(index.ctp)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        var ids = '';
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                ids = ids.concat(this.id).concat(',');
            }else{
                jAlert("Please choose items to delete");
            }
        });
        if (ids != ''){
            jConfirm('Delete?', 'Confirm',function(r){
                if(r==true){
                    ht = $.ajax({
                        url: 'items/delete/'.concat(ids),
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    });
                    location.reload(true);
                }

            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

---

(controller.php#function delete())

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('Deleted!, true));
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
```

Comment: check the value of `ids` use firebug or alert

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP's session flash is usually pretty reliable.

Perhaps your browser is not reliably doing a hard refresh with `location.reload(true)`.  Try `window.location = window.location.href + "?nocache=" + new Date().getTime()` to manually clear the cache and see if that helps at all.